# Spring MVC/Hibernate/mySQL "read" is always null

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-mvc

I've read through a few posts and I am not able to figure out what I am doing wrong here.

I have a simple Stock Quote web app that reads from a mySQL database. For now, all I am trying to accomplish is a "search" (read) of a symbol from the DB.

I can hard-code the symbol and it works as it is suppose to, however when I type a symbol into the actual field, it is read as 'null' and nothing happens. I'm new to this and only started coding in May, so I know I am most likely just overlooking something.

Any help will be appreciated, as I have been working on this for about a week and I just can't figure out what's going on. I'm going to school online so I don't have a lot of people to reach out to! Thanks!

Controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/stockQuote")
public class StockQuoteController {

// inject StockService
@Autowired
private StockService stockQuoteService;

@RequestMapping("/list")
public String listStocks (Model theModel) throws IOException {

    // get the quotes form the dao
    List<StockQuote> theQuote = stockQuoteService.getStockQuotes();

    // add the customers to the model
    theModel.addAttribute("stockQuote", theQuote);
    return "list-stocks";

}


@GetMapping("/index")
public String setupForm(Map<String, Object> map){
    StockQuote stockQuote = new StockQuote();
    map.put("student", stockQuote);
    map.put("studentList", stockQuoteService.getStockQuotes());
    return "search";
}

@PostMapping("/doSearch")
public String doActions(@ModelAttribute StockQuote stockQuote, Model theModel, String symbol) throws IOException {

    List<StockQuote> theQuote = stockQuoteService.searchQuotes(symbol);

    theModel.addAttribute("stockQuote", theQuote);

    return "search";

}
```

}

StockQuoteDAOimpl:

```
@Repository
public class StockQuoteDAOimpl implements StockQuoteDAO {
//I need to inject the session factory
@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;



@Override
public List<StockQuote> getStockQuote() {

    // I need to get the current hibernate session
    Session currentSession = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

    // create a query

    Query<StockQuote> theQuery = currentSession.createQuery("from StockQuote order by symbol", StockQuote.class);

    // execute query and get result list
    List<StockQuote> stockQuotes = theQuery.getResultList();

    // return list of stock quotes

    return stockQuotes;
}

@Override
public List<StockQuote> searchQuotes(String symbol) {


 Session currentSession = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
 sessionFactory.openSession();

 Query<StockQuote> theQuery = currentSession.createQuery("from StockQuote where symbol = '" + symbol + "'",
            StockQuote.class);

    List<StockQuote> stockQuotes = theQuery.getResultList();


    return stockQuotes;
}
```

}

StockQuoteServiceImpl:

```
@Service
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class StockQuoteServiceImpl implements StockService {

@Autowired // injecting our StockQuoteDAO
private StockQuoteDAO stockQuoteDAO;

@Override
@Transactional // handles DB transactions at the service level
public List<StockQuote> getStockQuotes() {
    return stockQuoteDAO.getStockQuote();
}

@Override
@Transactional
public List<StockQuote> searchQuotes(String symbol) {
    return stockQuoteDAO.searchQuotes(symbol);
}
```

}

StockQuote DAO: 
    @Entity
    @Indexed
    @EnableTransactionManagement
    @Table(name = "stock_quotes")
    public class StockQuote extends StockData {

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id")
private int id;

@Column(name = "price", nullable = false, length = 20)
@org.hibernate.search.annotations.Field(index = Index.YES, analyze = Analyze.YES, store = Store.NO)
private BigDecimal price;

@Column(name = "date", nullable = false, length = 20)
@org.hibernate.search.annotations.Field(index = Index.YES, analyze = Analyze.YES, store = Store.NO)
private Date date;

@Column(name = "symbol", nullable = false, length = 20)
@org.hibernate.search.annotations.Field(index = Index.YES, analyze = Analyze.YES, store = Store.NO)
private String symbol;


public StockQuote() {}

public StockQuote(String symbol, BigDecimal price, Date date) {
    super();
    this.price = price;
    this.date = date;
    this.symbol = symbol;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public BigDecimal getPrice() {
    return price;
}

public void setPrice(BigDecimal price) {
    this.price = price;
}

public Date getDate() {
    return date;
}

public void setDate(Date date) {
    this.date = date;
}

public String getSymbol() {
    return symbol;
}

public void setSymbol(String symbol) {
    this.symbol = symbol;
}
```

}

Search.jsp:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Stock Quote Query</title>

<link type="text/css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/css/style.css">

<link type="text/css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/css/add-customer-style.css">
```

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="header">
    <h2>Easy Quote Query</h2>
</div>
</div>
<div id="container">
<html>
<body>
<h2>Search for Stock</h2>

  <form:form action="doSearch" method="post" 
 modelAttribute="stockQuote">

    Symbol: <input type="search" name="searchText"/><br/>

    <br><br>

    <input type="submit" name="action" value="search"/>



</form:form>

<br><br>

<h2>Found Stocks</h2>
<table border="1">
    <th>Symbol</th>
    <th>Price</th>
    <th>Date</th>
    <c:forEach items="${stockQuote}" var="stock">
        <tr>
            <td>${stock.symbol}</td>
            <td>${stock.price}</td>
            <td>${stock.date}</td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</table>



</body>
</html>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured this out myself:

The issue was I wasn't mapping the symbol to the view. I added @ModelAttribute("searchText") which maps to the search field in my view (name="searchText") and it now works:

```
 @PostMapping("/doSearch")
 public String doActions(@ModelAttribute StockQuote stockQuote, Model 
 theModel, @ModelAttribute("searchText") String symbol) throws 


IOException {

  List<StockQuote> theQuote = 
  stockQuoteService.searchQuotes(symbol);
  theModel.addAttribute("stockQuote", theQuote);

  return "search";

 }
```